# "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" when using .add to add array to list. Any work around ? (Python)

Tags: python, hash, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to implement a breadth first search and am getting "TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" on the visited.add(state) command. The initState input is an array of numbers ([2,2,0,0,1]) and the return value of future_State() is a list of arrays in the same format. Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Some research pointed to a **hash**() method but I couldnt get it to work :/

```
      def BFS(initState):
            initState = currentState
            if isGoal(initState) :
                return initState

            visited = set()
            queue = [initState]

            while queue:
                state = queue.pop()
                if isGoal(state) == True:
                    return state

                visited.add(state)

                for child in future_State(state):
                    if child in visited:
                        continue
                    if child not in queue:
                        queue.append(child)
```

Comment: Use tuples for your states instead of lists

Comment: try with a `tuple`: `visited.add(tuple(state))` instead of your line: `visited.add(state)`. More information: http://net-informations.com/python/iq/unhashable.htm

Comment: So that worked but now I am getting the same error for "if child in visited:". What all in this function should be changed to a tuple for everything to be consistent?

Comment: you have to either change future_State to return tuples or convert the child generated to a tuple

Answer (score 1):

The sets in Python are implemented with an hash table.
The error message you get means that you can't add a list to a set, because the hash key can't be computed for that type of variable (the list).
If you want to add the values of **state** into the **visited** array, you can perform a union:

```
visited = visited.union(state)
```

Otherwise, if you want that each element of the set is a list, you should use a list for **visited** instead of a set and implement a solution to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem appears to be present in the for loop block just below it as well. Any ideas how to implement the same logic there?